# PDO , не могу подключиться к БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Я новичок , использую OpenServer, недавно начал изучать PDO и почему-то , когда пытаюсь подключиться к БД выскакивает ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'al'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

На всякий случай , вот мой PHP код:

```
$user = 'al';
$password='0000';

$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=site;charset=utf8', $user, $password);    
} 

catch (PDOException $e){
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: ту ты подключался нормально https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301291/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-sqlstatehy0002019

Comment: логин/пароль видимо не подходят

Comment: @Jean-Claude все совпадает

Comment: Почему все видят, что логин и пароль совсем другие, а ты один так уверен, что "всё совпадает"?